# SCSS: Get more detailed output information

Tags: css, sass

I have a complex custom built SCSS framework that where mixins can call on other mixins.

For example

```
@mixin red-combo {
@include red-text;
@include red-background;
} 


.div-red {
@include red-combo;
}
```

In the output CSS, the line comments will only point to `red-text` and `red-background`. That fact that `red-combo` was used to 'call' `red-text` and `red-background` is ignored.

Is there any way to make the line comments more detailed, so that `red-combo` can showed in the line comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Only one reference is supported per block.

The introduction of [source maps](http://snugug.com/musings/debugging-sass-source-maps) does not make a lot of difference either. It would support references for individual properties, yet one reference per property is still a limitation.